# Differentiate databricks streaming queries in datadog

Tags: monitoring, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, datadog

I am trying to set up a dashboard on Datadog that will show me the streaming metrics for my streaming job. The job itself contains two tasks one task has 2 streaming queries and the other has 4 (Both tasks use the same cluster). I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/databricks/?tab=driveronly#configuration) to install Datadog on the driver node. However when I go to datadog and try to create a dashboard there is no way to differentiate between the 6 different streaming queries so they are all lumped together (none of the tags for the metrics are different per query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found there is an option you can enable via the init script called [enable_query_name_tag](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/47d3179ead1fec090195d989ed7583d48a8c1d9e/spark/datadog_checks/spark/data/conf.yaml.example#L146) which is disabled by default as it can cause there to be a ton of tags created when you are not using query names.

The modification is shown here:

```
instances:
    - spark_url: http://\$DB_DRIVER_IP:\$DB_DRIVER_PORT
      spark_cluster_mode: spark_standalone_mode
      cluster_name: \${hostip}
      streaming_metrics: true
      enable_query_name_tag: true <----
```